# I have trouble about pinging pc1 to pc3 and pc2 to pc3 but the pc3 can successfully ping pc1 and pc3

Tags: ping, troubleshooting, desktop-computer, cisco-packet-tracer

I have trouble about pinging pc1 to pc3 and pc2 to pc3 but the pc3 can successfully ping pc1 and pc3.

This is EIGRP packet tracer that allows routers to connect pcs to pcs:

[image: this is EIGRP packet tracer that allows routers to connect pcs to pcs]

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser! Please [edit] your question checking for the correctness of the info. Do you really mean PC3 is able to ping PC1 and PC3 _itself_ or is that a typo? Moreover, please add the info if PC1 is able to ping PC1 itself and PC2. The same for PC2, if it is able to ping PC2 itself and PC1... if could be that PCx do not answer to ping because of some firewall rule...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know how your configuration is, but what you can do is to follow the ICMP packets via the Simulation Feature in Packet Tracer. You will then be able to see on which router the packet stops, it'll show a blinking "X" on the packet – which symbolizes that the packet is dropped. If you then click on this packet (with the blinking "X") you can see a description of why it is stopped/dropped. Hopefully then you can figure out what causes the pings to not be successful.

Here's a quick tutorial on how to use the Simulation Mode in Packet Tracer:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oNWJWN9m7M